Dockerized Flask App Unable to Persist Data in MongoDB – No Errors in Logs but No Data in DB
I'm working on a Flask application running in a Docker container that connects to MongoDB, also running in a separate container. Everything starts up without any errors, and the MongoDB connection is successfully established as indicated by the logs. However, when I perform operations like user signup, no new data appears in the MongoDB database.
The containers are running and communicating without errors, and I’ve ensured that the MongoDB user has the necessary permissions. attaching all necessary files
Environment:
Python: 3.9
MongoDB: 4.0.8
Docker: Running with Docker Compose
Dockerfile ->
FROM python:3.9-slim

WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    python3-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY req.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r req.txt
RUN pip install gunicorn

COPY . .

RUN mkdir -p logs

RUN useradd -m appuser && chown -R appuser:appuser /app
USER appuser

EXPOSE 5001

CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5001", "--workers", "4", "--timeout", "120", "app:app"]

docer compose ->
version: '3'

services:
  flask:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: <my-flask-image>:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    ports:
      - "6001-6003:5001"
    environment:
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://<my-username>:<my-password>@mongodb:27017/<my-db>?authSource=admin
      APP_ENV: "prod"
      APP_DEBUG: "False"
      APP_PORT: 5001
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/app/logs
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - backend
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "10m"
        max-file: "3"

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.0.8
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: mongod --auth
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: <my-username>
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: <my-password>
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: admin 
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
      - ./init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
    driver: local

MongoDB Initialization Script (init-mongo.js) ->
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');

db.createUser({
  user: '<my-username>',
  pwd: '<my-password>',
  roles: [
    { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'clusterAdmin', db: 'admin' }
  ]
});

db = db.getSiblingDB('<my-db>');
db.createUser({
  user: '<my-username>',
  pwd: '<my-password>',
  roles: [
    { role: 'readWrite', db: '<my-db>' },
    { role: 'dbAdmin', db: '<my-db>' }
  ]
});

config/settings.py ->
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

# MongoDB Configuration
MONGO_URI = os.getenv('MONGO_URI', 'mongodb://<my-username>:<my-password>@mongodb:27017/<my-db>?authSource=admin')
DB_NAME = '<my-db>'

config/db.py ->
from pymongo import MongoClient
import logging

class Database:
    client = None
    db = None

    @classmethod
    def initialize(cls):
        """Initialize database connection with retries"""
        cls.client = MongoClient(
            MONGO_URI,
            maxPoolSize=50,
            waitQueueTimeoutMS=2500,
            connectTimeoutMS=2500,
            serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000
        )
        cls.db = cls.client[DB_NAME]
        cls._create_indexes()
        logging.info("MongoDB connection successful")

    @classmethod
    def _create_indexes(cls):
        """Create necessary indexes"""
        cls.db.tenants.create_index("tenant_name", unique=True)
        cls.db.tenant_configs.create_index("cypherDomain", unique=True)
        logging.info("MongoDB indexes created successfully")

    @classmethod
    def get_db(cls):
        """Get database instance with connection check"""
        if cls.db is None:
            cls.initialize()
        return cls.db

db_instance = Database()


When I start the application, all services come up without any errors. MongoDB and Flask both indicate successful connections, and I can see MongoDB indexes created successfully in the logs. However, when a signup request is made, it doesn’t reflect in the database.
LOGS ->
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:Application starting up
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:MongoDB URI: <my-url>
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:Log file location: logs/backend_20241113.log
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:Application starting up
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:MongoDB URI: <my-url>
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:MongoDB connection successful
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:Log file location: logs/backend_20241113.log
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:MongoDB indexes created successfully
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:MongoDB connection successful
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:Application starting up
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:MongoDB URI: <my-url>
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:Log file location: logs/backend_20241113.log
2024-11-13 20:24:07 INFO:root:MongoDB indexes created successfully
2024-11-13 20:24:08 INFO:root:MongoDB connection successful
2024-11-13 20:24:08 INFO:root:MongoDB indexes created successfully
2024-11-13 20:24:08 INFO:root:Application starting up
2024-11-13 20:24:08 INFO:root:MongoDB URI: <my-url>
2024-11-13 20:24:08 INFO:root:Log file location: logs/backend_20241113.log
2024-11-13 20:24:08 INFO:root:MongoDB connection successful
2024-11-13 20:24:08 INFO:root:MongoDB indexes created successfully
2024-11-13 20:25:32 INFO:root:Signup data: {'email': 'db2@gmail.com', 'password': 'test123', 'tenant_name': 'db2', 'authProvider': 'email'}


What could prevent data from being inserted into MongoDB?
I'm new to docker sorry if something is wrong or sounds dumb, but any help is highly highly appreciated :)

Is it the same user name you create? Why do you create the user in <my-db>?

I mean if somebody signs up would i not make an insert in the db? or have i got your question wrong?

You always return "MongoDB indexes created successfully" no matter if the index was created successfully or not. You need to check the return code of your command.

valide point sure can add the check, but not sure if that really is causing the data to not get inserted in the DB

Well, then you might get a proper error message which indicates your problem.

Your intention is not clear to me. Bear in mind, you created two different(!) users. One user scoped to admin database, the other one to <my-db>
When you connect with
mongodb://<my-username>:<my-password>@mongodb:27017/<my-db>?authSource=admin
then you try to connect with user admin.<my-username>
If you like to connect with user <my-db>.<my-username>, then you must use connection string
mongodb://<my-username>:<my-password>@mongodb:27017/<my-db>?authSource=<my-db>.
I don't know any reason, why users might be created anywhere else than admin. I would suggest:
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
db.createUser({
  user: 'admin-usern',
  pwd: 'password',
  roles: [
    { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'clusterAdmin', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' }
  ]
});
db.createUser({
  user: 'normal-user',
  pwd: 'password',
  roles: [
    { role: 'readWrite', db: '<my-db>' },
    { role: 'dbAdmin', db: '<my-db>' }
  ]
});

Then you can connect always with authSource=admin
Role { role: 'clusterAdmin', db: 'admin' } is mostly relevant on sharded cluster, I don't think you have that. Thus, you may skip it.
Maybe, instead of
[
    { role: 'userAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'readWriteAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' },
    { role: 'dbAdminAnyDatabase', db: 'admin' }
]

simply grant
{ role: 'root', db: 'admin' }


appreciate the response, but is this what your saying?
db = db.getSiblingDB('admin');
db.createUser({
user: 'my-username',
pwd: 'my-password',
roles: [
{ role: 'root', db: '' }
]
});
db.createUser({
user: 'my-username', // should it be same as above or different?? for username as well as password
pwd: 'my-password',
roles: [
{ role: 'readWrite', db: '' },
{ role: 'dbAdmin', db: '' }
]
});

As said, it is not clear to me what you like to do. In fact you created two completely different users (even if you use the same username). Is that want you want? What is your intention?

I am sorry if i confused you, and thank you for being so patient, no i obviously just want one user (maybe if this is what you interpret) -> i have this flask app with a bunch of API's that i just want to interact with mongo and all of this to be dockerized and just want to deploy them on digital ocean (now for this if i'm not wrong one user is enough right???)
additional context ->
code for signup endpoint -
https://dpaste.org/mxiQB
mongo URI-
mongodb://:@localhost:27017/?authSource=

Then create just one user (in admin database) and grant all these roles to this user and connect with authSource=admin. Actually, { role: 'readWrite', db: '<my-db>' } and { role: 'dbAdmin', db: '<my-db>' } are not needed, because they are already included in readWriteAnyDatabase and dbAdminAnyDatabase

Sorry I have no clue about docker and flask. And without any error message it is difficult to provide any help.

no worries man thanks for the reply :)
